# BMC Remedy 9 Powershell Integration

Tags: powershell, remedy

I am looking for information or help on querying the BMC Remedy ARsystem

Currently under Remedy 7 we are using the ODBC driver installed with the client application to query.

We are migrating to Remedy 9 and solely using the web interface rather than an installed client (not sure they even have a client for 9)

I have no idea how to query the new system.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Remedy 9 has a REST API](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/ars9000/BMC+Remedy+AR+System+REST+API+overview) that can be queried via HTTP calls.

I've actually recently created a PowerShell Module for interacting with the Remedy API which you can find details of here: https://github.com/markwragg/Powershell-Remedy

It's open source, so you're free to reuse or clone and modify it. I have developed it against a single internal system so i'd be keen to hear whether it works for other systems as it's difficult for me to tell whether some aspects of my company's Remedy system are customized.

Comment: That looks fantastic, I have one major issue though, the API link doesn't work.  I work in a big company so I was hoping not to have to make formal requests to make changes as its paperwork would be awful.... but is it possible for them to have disabled the REST API?

Comment: Yes I think so, or maybe to have not enabled it and/or have made it accessible over the network.

Comment: Well that is unfortunate,  either way thank you for your response, the code looks great and I will be very much using it.  For now I will mark your answer as correct as it appears to give me everything I will need, once they let me in the API.  Thanks again